# Define custom User-agent header in the HTTP request?

Tags: iphone, http, http-headers, user-agent

I would like to get a glimpse of web-sites created for iPhone devices. In order to be able to view those sites I have to modify the User-agent header in the HTTP request that my browser sends. That way I can trick the web-server into believing that my browser is an iPhone browser, and then the web-server would send my the iPhone version of the web-site.

So, how can I modify the User-agent header that my browser sends in each HTTP request.
Maybe there is an Firefox plug-in that allows modifying request headers?
Also, I think I heard that Safari allows that somehow....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you can do this with [Modify Headers](http://modifyheaders.mozdev.org/) add-on for Firefox.

Comment: btw the official addon URL is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/967/

Answer (score 3):

You can try [the user-agent switcher plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59/).

Answer (score 2):

First, there's the following plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59/

Also, there's Firefox configuration: type "about:config" as URL in Firefox, find general.useragent.* properties there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a browser add-on in order to add a custom User-Agent string in your HTTP header. Chrome has added this feature to developer tools.

Open the developer tools and click on the `Toggle Device Toolbar` option or press `cmd+shift+M` to open it. You can select a device user agent from the presets or you can also define a custom device like mentioned in the below screenshot.

[image]